# Adjoint operator on $\mathbb{L} ^2 _\mathbb{R}$ of $\frac{d}{dx}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, adjoint-operators

If A is a linear operator defined on $\mathbb{L} ^2 _\mathbb{R}$ of $\frac{d}{dx}$ then its adjoint must satisfy the property:
$$(A^*f,g) = (f,Ag) \\ f,g \in \mathbb{L} ^2 _\mathbb{R}$$$

Now if $A = \frac{d}{dx}$, then how can I find $A^*$? I am unsure of this because first how is the scalar product defined on $\mathbb{L} ^2 _\mathbb{R}$? Do I just need to "plug in" $f,g$ in the scalar product and then work it out from there? I know the answer is $-\frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: In $L^2,$ the usual inner product is $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) g(x)\,d\mu,$ a Lebesgue integral. However, if your functions are differentiable, then they're continuous, and hence Riemann integrable.

Comment: I believe integration by parts is useful here.

Comment: @Math1000 yeah I figured that would be helpful as inside the integral you would have something like $u \ dv$.